# How to grep the names of files and store it in output with python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, unix

I have a directory that has multiple files and I want to grep only `test.uwsgi.log` files and remove the .uwsgi.log part. After greping the names I store it in a output file.

Here is what I got:

```
import subprocess
testlist = “cd /root/test/ && ls | grep ‘uwsgi.log' |sed 's/\.uwsgi.log\>//g' > /root/test/testlist.txt"
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', testlist])
```

and the output is :

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Can someone educate me on how to achieve this without the subprocess module and use python only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python alone:

```
import os

for _, dirs, files in os.walk('/root/test/'):
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.writelines("{}\n".format(f) for f in files if f.endswith('uwsgi.log'))
```

output.txt is as expected:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Notice I added `\n` to each element in the list comprehension . as `writelines` does not do it automatically.

Comment: for many files it might cause memory issue, avoid using split and use generator comprehension instead `.writelines("{}\n".format(x) for f in files)` get +1 but edit